# Oracle Statement to fetch data and put results in columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I know maybe my question is kinda weird but I didn't use Oracle before,
I have this statement to select count of specific number in column and output result

```
select count(*)as Step1 from ALLVALUES WHERE NAME LIKE '%VALUE%' AND systime between caltosys(&t1) and caltosys(&t2) AND ROWNUM <= 90000 AND VALUE ='48'
```

This will output the results like this

```
------
Step1
------
20
------
```

I need to fetch multiple conditions and put each result in column for example

```
select count(*)as Step1 from ALLVALUES WHERE NAME LIKE '%VALUE%' AND systime between caltosys(&t1) and caltosys(&t2) AND ROWNUM <= 90000 AND VALUE ='48'
select count(*)as Step2 from ALLVALUES WHERE NAME LIKE '%VALUE%' AND systime between caltosys(&t1) and caltosys(&t2) AND ROWNUM <= 90000 AND VALUE ='49'
...
```

And output belike this

```
------------------------------
Step1 | Step2 | Step3 | Step4
------------------------------
20  | 5     | 1     | 4
------------------------------
```

Is that possible in my current situation?

I tried to write as suggested statement

```
select to_char(systocal(systime),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3') as Time,
COUNT(case WHEN value ='48.8' then value end) as Step1,
COUNT(CASE WHEN value ='48.75' then value end) as Step2,
COUNT(CASE WHEN value ='48.7' then value end)as Step3,
COUNT(CASE WHEN value ='48.68' then value end)as Step4,
COUNT(CASE WHEN value ='48.6' then value end)as Step5,
COUNT(CASE WHEN value ='48.58' then value end)as Step6,
COUNT(CASE WHEN value ='48.55' then value end)as Step7,
COUNT(CASE WHEN value ='48.52' then value end)as Step8,
from MEA where ID = 5570 AND systime between caltosys(&t1) and caltosys(&t2) AND ROWNUM <= 100
```

&t1 -  &t2 are variables for time

But keep giving me missing expression 936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` to reorganise rows to columns. One way to write your query (omitting the time columns for simplicity) would be

```
select * from
(select value from MEA where ID = 5570)
pivot
(count(*) for value in 
  (
    '48.8' as Step1,
    '48.75' as Step2,
    '48.7' as Step3,
    '48.68' as Step4,
    '48.6' as Step5,
    '48.58' as Step6,
    '48.55' as Step7,
    '48.52' as Step8
  )
);
```

See the [Pivoting Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-05BB22CD-0F53-4C90-AE84-CE3F88DBD591) chapter of the Oracle Database Data Warehousing Guide for more information and examples.

Comment: I think this solution is achieved my question,  just still something maybe no related but values in my database are like 6 digits on right 48.786543, but in steps i need to round them is that achievable in same statement?

Comment: I did round on value select (round(value, 2)), thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation, relaxing the filter in the `where` clause in include all the values you're interesting in, and case expressions to only count matching rows:

```
select
  count(case when value = '48' then value end) as Step1,
  count(case when value = '49' then value end) as Step2,
  count(case when value = '50' then value end) as Step3,
  count(case when value = '51' then value end) as Step4
from ALLVALUES WHERE NAME LIKE '%VALUE%'
AND systime between caltosys(&t1) and caltosys(&t2)
AND ROWNUM <= 90000
AND VALUE in ('48', '49', '50', '51')
```

You could also use the `pivot` clause to achieve the same thing.

The rownum filter looks odd though - partly because of the high number, but mostly because you're applying it on an unordered result set, so the results will be indeterminate (if there are more than 90000 matching rows anyway).

Comment: My statement here but keep giving me error missing expression 936

Comment: @hawkiq - what values are you providing for t1 and t2, and what data type does your `caltosys` take as arguments and return, and what data type is `systime`? (This [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d6cce107a3f9eef8e0f7cebc219137aa) with fixed values and dummy function, so something else going on). Please add information as an edit to the question - including the function signature and example data/values.